# React onclick pass button api id to state

Tags: reactjs, api, button, onclick, state

I have a simple aip with an array with 4 different ids. In react I've made an `<ul>` with a button for each of the ids. When I click the button, I want to change the `state.id` and `console.log` the new `state.id` with the new specific button id value from the api (eventually I want to change some render depending on the button I press).

[image]

[image]

I need to press two times on one of the buttons to console.log my desired id, I need the state to change on the first click (to make some changes to some new render).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the React docs for [setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to
> update the component. For better perceived performance, React may
> delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React
> does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

Try logging this.state inside your render function and you will see how it actually IS happening after the first click - but your log is displaying it before the state updates.

Answer (score 0):

[setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)  : setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied.